# Traveling for tourism with Schengen business visa single Entry from Sweden to Norway

Tags: visas, schengen, norway, change-purpose-of-travel

Can one travel for tourism to Norway with Schengen business visa- single entry  (given for Sweden)?

Comment: Going for a short time in Norway while you are in Sweden for business is no problem. Foregoing your originally planned trip to do tourism in Norway instead could be an issue. We have many questions about this, the best is to look at the archive.